# (dataframe_image error) OsError: Chrome executable not able to be found on your machine

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, os, manjaro

Estoy haciendo un bot para Discord y en él voy a mostrar tablas estilizadas, y la mejor manera que encontré es convertirlas en una imagen para que el bot simplemente las envíe.
Pero me sale un error:

> OsError: Chrome executable not able to be found on your machine

Uso manjaro y ya intenté instalar chromedriver que viene en AUR pero no funciona.

Mi código simplificado:

```py
import dataframe_image as dfi
import pandas as pd

test_list = [['A','B','C'],[1,2,3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(test_list, columns=['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'])

dfi.export(df,'dataframe.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

un gusto en saludar

ejecuté tu código y no tiene errores y me generó la imagen del Dataframe.

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3
0        A        B        C
1        1        2        3
```

Podrías mostrar en detalle un poco más el error que te arroja, yo uso Debian e instalé y debes asegurarte que el binario ChromeDriver tiene habilitado el path

```
sudo mv -f ~/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

espero haber sido de ayuda

saludos